# How to get distinct value using cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I am trying to get the value (date) from a table with each row as uniquely identified and I am using the cursor to fetch the value. Below is the code for the same where `BM_RLOS_DisbursementCallsGrid` is the table which includes `bpm_refno` as primary key and `disbursal_Date` as a date.

One `bpm_refno` can occur multiple times with different date, I will have to acquire the `bpm_refno` with max date though when I am running only Select statement, it's giving the result as expected with every row with different `bpm_refno` and maximum date but when I am running through cursor and printing the value, it's taking too long time to process the result and also the result is replicating, I want distinct row.

Note: I am new in the cursor.

Also, it will be a great help if anyone can suggest, how to add up the cursor value for every unique id's.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test1
AS
    DECLARE @wi_name NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @date DATETIME;

    DECLARE fetch_disb_date CURSOR FOR
    'SELECT DISTINCT '''+ bpm_referenceno, max(callexecutiondate)
    FROM BM_RLOS_DisbursementCallsGrid
    WHERE calldescription='MG Contract Creation' 
      AND callstatus='SUCCESS'
    GROUP by bpm_referenceno

    BEGIN
        OPEN fetch_disb_date;
        FETCH next FROM  fetch_disb_date
        INTO @wi_name,@date;
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
        BEGIN
            PRINT @wi_name;
            PRINT @date;
        END;
        CLOSE fetch_disb_date;
        DEALLOCATE fetch_disb_date;
    END
```

Comment: Cursor or not makes no DISTINCT difference.

Comment: Means, we can't get distinct value using Cursor? How we can achieve this using procedure.

Comment: Why do you need to use a `CURSOR` in the first place? Also, your declaration for the cursor is invalid; it looks like like a mis-mash of inline and dynamic SQL. Finally, you should really consider using some whitespace to format your queries. Don't Left align all your code. For example, you should really be intending inside an `BEGIN...END`.

Comment: If you are using group by, you don't need distinct

Comment: A _cursor_ to get distinct values isn't the approach I'd use. Make sure the select returns no duplicates, and you're there!